# Use macro define between module interface and implementation unit

Tags: c++, macros, c++20, preprocessor

I have a module interface unit in a SomeModule.ixx file, with some functions prototypes generated using a preprocessor macro:

```
export module SomeModule;

#define GENERATED_FUNCTION(ret, name, ...) typedef ret name##_prototype(__VA_ARGS__); \

#define GENERATED_FUNCTIONS_LIST \
GENERATED_FUNCTION(void, some_function, int param1, double param2) \
GENERATED_FUNCTION(void, some_function2, int param1, float param2) \
GENERATED_FUNCTION(void, some_function3, int* param1, int** param2) \

GENERATED_FUNCTIONS_LIST

#undef GENERATED_FUNCTION

export struct SomeStruct {
    void init();

#define GENERATED_FUNCTION(ret, name, ...) \
name##_prototype* name;

    GENERATED_FUNCTIONS_LIST
#undef GENERATED_FUNCTION
};
```

and an implementation unit in SomeModuleImpl.cpp :

```
module SomeModule;

void SomeStruct::init() {

#define GENERATED_FUNCTION(ret, name, ...) \
    name = NULL;

    GENERATED_FUNCTIONS_LIST
#undef GENERATED_FUNCTION

}
```

I want to set some value for the methods in `SomeStruct`, again using the macro, however I'm getting this error in the module implementation:

```
E0020   identifier "GENERATED_FUNCTIONS_LIST" is undefined
```

Is there any way to share macro defines between module interface and implementation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there any way to share macro defines between module interface and implementation?

Yes, the same one you used to use: a header file. Put your `GENERATED_FUNCTIONS_LIST` macro in a header file. This is pretty standard for [X-macro-style code](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/x-macros/info).

Modules don't include macros, so it doesn't change much of what you have to do there.

Comment: Is there any way to do this kind of meta-programming using only modules? I was under the impression that modules were supposed to completely replace header files, is it not the case?

Comment: @imad: No and no. Modules replace actual C++, but macros are part of the preprocessor, not really part of the language. So if you're doing a bunch of macro stuff, or if you're building a macro-based interface for your library, you will have to use headers.